# What does the yellow star mean on the minimap in Hitman Blood Money?

Tags: hitman-blood-money

[image]

What does the star with an S in it represent?

Comment: I am really tempted to answer this since I played Blood Money to death but I am not 100% sure what I am thinking that represents is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "guard's quarters" (typically where you steal surveillance tapes) - see here:
http://www.gamesradar.com/cheats/3308/

search that. It gives no picture but it describes this as a star on the map.